# Selecting 1 columns from 2 rows with group by

Tags: mysql

I am having a challenge in trying to figure a query out.

I have a table with 2 columns:

TOPIC_ID & USER_ID, Both are INTEGER(11)

```
TOPIC_ID    USER_ID
-- -- --    -------
1           1
1           2

2           10
2           20

3           1
3           10

4           3
4           20
```

The result I would like is to see if 2 users already have a topic id or if one needs to be created;

So for example, if I check USER_ID 1 & 2; They have TOPIC_ID 1;
If I check USER_ID 10 & 20, they have TOPIC_ID 2;
If I check USER_ID 99 & 88, they dont have a TOPIC_ID, so it needs to be created;

How would you recommend going about getting this? I came with the following 2 queries that produce the result but I am wondering for your suggestions.

```
SELECT      TOPIC_ID
FROM        TOPIC_USERS
GROUP BY    TOPIC_ID
HAVING      MIN(USER_ID) = 1
AND         MAX(USER_ID) = 2;

SELECT      IF(COUNT(*),TU1.TOPIC_ID,0)
FROM        TOPIC_USERS AS TU1
            LEFT JOIN TOPIC_USERS AS TU2 ON (TU1.TOPIC_ID = TU2.TOPIC_ID)
WHERE       TU1.USER_ID = 1
AND         TU2.USER_ID = 2;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: INSERT INTO a_table VALUES (some_topic_id,98)

Comment: @Strawberry not sure what your intention was but this is not what I am looking for.